# Cart Summary expanded

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, order-summary

**On our checkout page** we have the product list and the shipping options within a **collapsible menu**.
I can not seem to get it expanded. I found the relevant passage in the **_cart.less**.

Is anyone able to help me with this issue?

[image]

```
 //
//  Shopping cart
//  ---------------------------------------------

.checkout-cart-index {
    .page-main {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .page-title-wrapper {
        padding-left: @layout__width-xs-indent;
        padding-right: @layout__width-xs-indent;
    }
}

//  Cart container
.cart-container {
    .form-cart {
        &:extend(.abs-shopping-cart-items all);
    }
}

//  Summary block
.cart-summary {
    &:extend(.abs-add-box-sizing all);
    .lib-css(background, @sidebar__background-color);
    margin-bottom: @indent__m;
    padding: 1px 0 @indent__m;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    > .title {
        .lib-font-size(24);
        display: none;
        font-weight: @font-weight__light;
        margin: 12px 0;
    }

    .block {
        form:not(:last-of-type) {
            .fieldset {
                margin: 0 0 @indent__m;
            }
        }

        .price {
            font-weight: @font-weight__bold;
        }

        .field {
            margin: 0 0 16px;
            &.note {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .actions-toolbar {
            > .primary {
                text-align: left;
                .action.primary {
                    &:extend(.abs-revert-to-action-secondary all);
                    width: auto;
                }
            }
        }

        .fieldset.estimate {
            > .legend,
            > .legend + br {
                &:extend(.abs-no-display all);
            }
        }
        &:extend(.abs-cart-block all);
        .title {
            strong {
                .lib-font-size(14);
                font-weight: @font-weight__semibold;
            }
        }
        .item-options {
            margin: 0 0 16px;
            .field {
                .radio {
                    float: left;
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }
                .radio {
                    + .label {
                        display: block;
                        margin: 0;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        font-weight: 400;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .page-main & {
        .block {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    .checkout-methods-items {
        &:extend(.abs-reset-list all);
        margin: @indent__base 0 0;
        padding: 0 @mobile-cart-padding;
        text-align: center;
        .action.primary.checkout {
            &:extend(.abs-button-l all);
            width: 100%;
        }
        .item {
            margin-bottom: @indent__m;
            &:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    .message {
        padding-left: @indent__base;
        > *:first-child:before {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    &:extend(.abs-adjustment-incl-excl-tax all);
}

//  Totals block
.cart-totals {
    &:extend(.abs-sidebar-totals all);
    tbody,
    tfoot {
        .mark {
            text-align: left;
        }
    }
}

//  Products table
.cart {
    &.table-wrapper {
        .product-item-name > a {
            font-size: 14px;
            &, &:hover {
                color: @_link-color;
            }
        }
        .product-image-container {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 3px;
        }
        .cart {
            thead {
                tr th.col {
                    border-bottom: @border-width__base solid @border-color__base;
                    padding-bottom: 12px;
                    padding-top: 24px;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-weight: 600;
                }
            }
            tbody {
                td {
                    border: 0;
                }
            }
            > .item {
                border-bottom: @border-width__base solid @border-color__base;
                position: relative;
            }
        }
        .col {
            vertical-align: middle;
            &.price,
            &.subtotal,
            &.msrp {
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: center;
                &:extend(.abs-incl-excl-tax all);
            }
            &.subtotal .price {
                color: @theme-color;
            }
            &.qty {
                text-align: center;
                .label {
                    &:extend(.abs-visually-hidden all);
                }
                .input-text {
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 45px;
                }
                .field.qty {
                    min-width: 67px;
                }
            }
            > .price {
                .lib-css(color, @primary__color__lighter);
                .lib-font-size(18);
                font-weight: @font-weight__bold;
            }
        }

        .item-actions {
            td {
                padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-left: @mobile-cart-padding;
                padding-right: @mobile-cart-padding;
                white-space: normal;
            }
        }
        .item {
            .col.item {
                display: block;
                min-height: 75px;
                padding: 15px @mobile-cart-padding @indent__s 90px;
                position: relative;
            }
        }

        .actions-toolbar {
            &:extend(.abs-add-clearfix all);
            min-height: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            position: relative;
            > .action-edit,
            > .action-delete {
                position: absolute;
                right: 16px;
                top: 0;
                .lib-icon-font(
                @icon-edit,
                @_icon-font-size: 18px,
                @_icon-font-line-height: 20px,
                @_icon-font-text-hide: true,
                @_icon-font-color: @minicart-icons-color,
                @_icon-font-color-hover: @primary__color,
                @_icon-font-color-active: @minicart-icons-color
                );
            }
            > .action-delete {
                &:extend(.abs-action-button-as-link all);
                right: 0;
                .lib-icon-font-symbol(
                @_icon-font-content: @icon-trash
                );
            }
        }
        .action {
            margin-right: 15px;
            &:last-child {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
            &.help.map {
                &:extend(.abs-action-button-as-link all);
                font-weight: @font-weight__regular;
            }
        }

        .product {
            &-item-photo {
                display: block;
                left: @mobile-cart-padding;
                max-width: 65px;
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 15px;
                width: 100%;
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
            }
            &-item-name {
                .lib-font-size(18);
                display: block;
                margin: 0;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        }
        .gift-registry-name-label {
            &:after {
                content: ':';
            }
        }

        //  Product options
        .item-options {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            &:extend(.abs-product-options-list all);
            &:extend(.abs-add-clearfix all);
        }

        .product-item-name + .item-options {
            margin-top: @indent__base;
        }

        .cart-tax-total {
            &:extend(.abs-tax-total all);
            &-expanded {
                &:extend(.abs-tax-total-expanded all);
            }
        }
        .product-image-wrapper {
            &:extend(.abs-reset-image-wrapper all);
        }
        .action.configure {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: @indent__s 0 0;
        }
        .item .message {
            margin-top: @indent__base;
        }
    }
}

//  Discount
.cart-discount {
    border-bottom: @border-width__base solid @border-color__base;
    clear: left;
    &:extend(.abs-discount-block all);
}

//  Empty cart
.cart-empty {
    padding-left: @layout__width-xs-indent;
    padding-right: @layout__width-xs-indent;
}

.cart-tax-info + .cart-tax-total {
    display: block;
}
```

}

Comment: you want it opened by default ?

Comment: Yes, I believe as it is now it hurts the customer experience

Comment: check in summary.phtml there should "collapse true/active" ..... I didn't check that same thing done for coupon code to make that opened by default

Comment: override this file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/ cart-items.html... and pass the class "active" ...

Comment: Sorry, when you say pass the class what do you mean?

Comment: when dropdown is active ... then a class "active" is added in section...so by deault you need to add this class ..... you will find it at above location...then override it in your extended checkout module ... do not change in vendor.......    you will find "block items-in-cart"  make it "block items-in-cart active"

Comment: I did override it at Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary with block items-in-cart active it did however not expand the menu. Could you perhaps post the code you used to make it expand?

Comment: not on system currently ...otherwise could post it

Comment: Would you mind posting it when you're on the system?

Comment: try below solution , tested on extended luma theme

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make **cart summary opened initially on page load**  do the following :

Go to your **core files** and **copy** `cart-items.html`

```
 vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

Place `cart-items.html`at below location in your custom theme, **create folder if doesn't exist** and **copy only required files**

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

In this you need to **update this line of code at line no 7/8.**

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
```

Here, you can **pass the active option** `('active': true)` to it. So the full line should be like so:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
```

**Now clear your cache**

```
pub/static
var/view_preprocessed
```

Hopefully this should help you.

You can run following **commands to remove your cache**

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/di/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: it sounds great , cheers !

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the way to have the shipping block in the cart summary extended as well. It is an extension of Manoj's answer so all the credit still goes to him.

[image]

In order to change shipping.phtml needs to be updated.

Shipping.phtml can be found in

**/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart**

shipping.phtml needs to be modified on line 12

from:

```
<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": true}}'>
```

to:

```
<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "active": true}}'>
```

and then needs to be placed in:

**app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name//Magento_Checkout/templates/cart**

then follow the same methods as Manoj to clear the cache.

I hope this can help someone in the future :)

Comment: great , you done the other things very well... this goes to for your work , cheres !