# Magento2: Order summary always expanded

Tags: magento2.3, order-summary

I am using **Magento 2.3.0** and I want the **Cart Order Summary** always expanded.

All solutions I have found wont work.
Is there any workaround or has something changed in 2.3?

Comment: show us the solutions you've tried

Comment: Hey Phil... i have tried this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196172/cart-summary-expanded?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this work around:

> First: Create a **requirejs-config.js** from path **app/code/Marcel/Summary/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
     map: {
         '*': {
             "Magento_Checkout/template/summary/cart-items.html": "Marcel_Summary/template/summary/cart-items.html"
         }
     }
 };
```

> Second: Create your **cart-items.html** from this path **app/code/Marcel/Summary/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong role="heading">
            <translate args="maxCartItemsToDisplay" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <translate args="'of'" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <span data-bind="text: getCartLineItemsCount()"></span>
            <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() === 1"/>
            <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() > 1"/>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content minicart-items" data-role="content" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block !important;">
        <div class="minicart-items-wrapper overflowed">
            <ol class="minicart-items">
                <each args="items()">
                    <li class="product-item">
                        <div class="product">
                            <each args="$parent.elems()" render=""/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </each>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After doing the above steps, make sure to run:

**`setup:upgrade`**
**`setup:static-content:deploy -f`**

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not working. But I think, i have made a mistake.
How does this path have to look like in config.js? "Magento_Checkout/template/summary/cart-items.html": "vendor_module/template/summary/cart-items.html",

Comment: you mean in requirejs-config.js?

Comment: it should look like in my answer above

Comment: and my answer works in my system

Comment: only if you have followed all the instruction I posted in my answer

Comment: I'm not familiar with "vendor_module" path. I have path like this:
"app/code/Marcel/Summary/view" as path...

Comment: ahh , you can make it `Marcel_Summary/template/summary/cart-items.html` you just changed the vendor_module (it's actually vendorName_moduleName)

Comment: I have updated the answer the same way you linked with your module name and vendor name

Comment: Thanks, but not the desired result. The summary block is always generated via JS and slides down....

Comment: if you can post a code it would be easier to debug it

Comment: Seems it do not load the new template. Have made some test-text within cart-items.html and it wont show. In Default/de_DE/requirejs/require.js the requirejs-config.js from this modul was not loaded.

Comment: you can try running setup:upgrade or can you send me your custom module where you do the overriding? I'll try to check from my local machine and check it

Comment: Realised that we are speaking about different templates. I mean my checkout template the "<div id="cart-totals" class="cart-totals" data-bind="scope:'block-totals'">" Block.